# What is a default port range for server.port=0 in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpserver

What is a default port range for `server.port=0` in Spring Boot application?

I'm using spring-boot 2.7 (with default tomcat server) and working with java 11.

Or the range differs depending on OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range for random ports depends on a couple of factors:

- All port numbers are 16-bit unsigned integers, so the highest possible value is 65535.
- Ports below 1024 are considered privileged ports on Unix-based systems (including macOS and Linux). Normal users can't open sockets on these ports, so typically, Spring Boot will not use them.
- Ports from 1024 to 49151 are known as the User or Registered Ports, and **ports from 49152 to 65535** are the Dynamic or Private Ports. **These are typically the ports Spring Boot might choose from**.

If you are not running Spring Boot with root or administrator privilege, then the random port is likely to be between 1024 and 65535 (this is not a strict rule and can be different based on your OS configuration).

However, Spring Boot doesn't set this range - the operating system's networking subsystem does. Spring Boot simply asks the OS to give it a available port, and the OS determines what port to hand out based on its own configuration.

Comment: For Windows non privileged user can we assume it will be ephemeral/dynamic port from range 49152 to 65535?

Comment: We can make an assumption but the actual range can be configured on a per-machine basis. The dynamic port range configured in the operating system where the application is running should be checked for a definitive answer.